# Multiple controller matching the request in attribute based routing asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is regarding to how to define routes in controller of asp.net mvc

1st controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("contact/Login")]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

2nd controller

```
[Route("{CategoryURL}/{Keywords}")]
public ActionResult BrowseProducts(string CategoryURL, string Keywords)
{

}
```

I am getting below error If try to access URL abc.com/contact/Login

> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can
>   happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested
>   URL. The request has found the following matching controller types:
>   abc.Controllers.AccountController abc.Controllers.CoursesController

My question is, I want to validate *{CategoryURL}* input's and also want to access URL "abc.com/contact/Login"

Comment: Your 2nd route matches `contact/Login` (because it has 2 segments). If they were in the same controller then precedence is honored, but because they are in different controllers, you need something to distinguish the routes, or use a route constraint

Comment: I think you should use routing constraint since first URL patterns are matched with second one, usually namespace constraint if both routes having different namespaces.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i use the constraint for the 2nd controller and now i am able to validate CategoryURL but is there any example of using constraint we can distinguish between this routes.

Comment: You have just indicated you have created a constraint that is working, so not sure what you asking

Comment: If you mean doing it without a route constraint, then your 2nd route attribute needs to be something like `[Route("BrowseProducts/{CategoryURL}/{Keywords}")]` (which is a more meaningful address any way)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your quick feedback i get my solution using constraint thanks for your response :)